# Views fields configuration is not working

Tags: views, entities, javascript

I set a few fields as *FIELDS* section of a view. the problem is when I click on the fields the `Style settings` ,`No results behavior` , `Rewrite results` and `More` links are not collapsible . this is the screenshot

[image]

what it is like that?

Comment: try [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module with jquery version 1.5 for admin pages.

Comment: @shrish I tried it but it didn't work :(

Comment: make sure your `jQuery update` and `Ctools` module is upto date

Comment: They are, the website was working , suddenly this thing happened!

Comment: Just to be sure, is it the issue that disappears when you open your developer tools widget in your brower?

Comment: This is a browser issue, open the same page in other browser and check.

Comment: @Smalution it wasn't because of browser ! checked in other browsers

Comment: @Djouuuuh what kind of widgets do you mean?

Comment: Dev tools when you press F12 in your browser

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you're not the only one to encounter this issue. Here are some similar situations:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2151785
- [Views UI doesn't provide links to expand fieldsets anymore](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45100/views-ui-doesnt-provide-links-to-expand-fieldsets-anymore)

It appears that no one has found out the solution yet. It doesn't seem to come from jQuery Update or backend theme. However, these advices show up each time:

- Make sure that the needed JavaScript file is loaded in the header of the node (`collapsible.js`)
- Perhaps a conflict with another module that would use Views hook. Disable enabled modules one by one and test.

If you find which module interferes with Views or why JS file is not loaded, I think you will make more than one happy people.

Comment: it has got nothing to `collapsible.js`! this file is not in the sites where they work well

Comment: Does the fieldset have the class "collapsible" like mine? <fieldset id="edit-options-style-settings" class="collapsible collapsed form-wrapper collapse-processed">

Comment: it has these classes `collapsible collapsed form-wrapper`

Comment: I also have a collapsible-div.js that comes from ctools module. Do you?

Comment: No I don't have that js file!

Comment: Ok. And do you have it "in the sites where they work well"? Maybe we're holding something :o

Comment: No it is not in there too! My website was working suddenly this happened!

Comment: Did you install a new module or a new library since then?

Comment: no but it reports this error in this address " `https://www.drupal.org/node/588186`

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when you have a javascript error, or using a custom admin theme which doesn't play well with the accordion/fieldset behaviors.

Open Javascript console (Usually F12) to see if there's any errors reported there.

If you're using a custom admin theme, try switching back to **Seven** theme

Comment: No javascript error was reported in Firebug, I tried Seven and Bartik, they both it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem.

I have custom module in which I have override javascript of contrib module Field group like this:

```
$javascript[drupal_get_path('module', 'field_group') . '/multipage/multipage.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'create_events') . '/js/multipage.js';
```

When I realized that I've added condition to override js file only on add content type event page or on edit page.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function create_events_js_alter(&$javascript) {
    if (request_uri() == '/node/add/event' || node_type_get_name(node_load(arg()[1])) == 'Event') {
        // override default multipage javascript to change button output
        $javascript[drupal_get_path('module', 'field_group') . '/multipage/multipage.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'create_events') . '/js/multipage.js';
    }
}
```

So maybe you can check if you are implementing hook_js_alter function and try to comment that out and try again.

Hope this will help someone.